# Changing Global: Text Area based on an exposed filter in views?

Tags: views

A client wants to display different text in a page depending on the value of the View's Exposed Filter.

I could throw this logic into the template.php or use javascript (showing and hiding a span depending on the value), but this feels like a very poor way to do this when considering maintainability?

Does there exist a Views plugin to perhaps show different text blocks in the header based on the value of an exposed filter?

Currently on Drupal 7.31 using [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). I'm open to using something other than Global: Text area if there is a better mechanism.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
hook_views_pre_render(&$view){
    $view->attachment_before = $view['exposed_input']['your_desired_field'];
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: I'm looking to add text to that area based on the value of the exposed filter. Would this be the appropriate hook to place a if (exp_Filter=='value') { $view->attachment_before .=  'Additional Text'; } ?

Comment: Yes, you can check the array 'exposed_input' with (you need the devel module installed and enabled) dpm($view['exposed_input']) to find out the key for your desired value. Then compare it to whatever condition through your if statement.

Comment: did you solve it?